# Trying to insert data in a manyToOne field - could not execute statement [Field 'event_id' doesn't have a default value]

Tags: java, spring-boot, hibernate

I'm trying to insert data in my table EventUser which has 3 FK's, eventId, userId, userFunctionId. I create first an event with id 1 and try to link everything in this table by postman :

```
localhost:8080/api/event/1/updateUsers

[
    {"userId": 1, "userFunctionName": "door"},
    {"userId": 2, "userFunctionName": "bar"}
]
```

I have this error message in the console :

```
2023-10-09 21:40:35 [http-nio-8080-exec-3] WARN  o.h.e.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper - SQL Error: 1364, SQLState: HY000
2023-10-09 21:40:35 [http-nio-8080-exec-3] ERROR o.h.e.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper - Field 'event_id' doesn't have a default value
2023-10-09 21:40:35 [http-nio-8080-exec-3] ERROR c.i.a.e.s.impl.EventUserService - JPA system exception while adding event
org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaSystemException: could not execute statement [Field 'event_id' doesn't have a default value] [insert into `event_user` (`created_at`,`created_by`,`modified_at`,`modified_by`,`id`) values (?,?,?,?,?)]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaDialect.convertHibernateAccessException(HibernateJpaDialect.java:320)
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaDialect.translateExceptionIfPossible(HibernateJpaDialect.java:229)
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager.doCommit(JpaTransactionManager.java:565)
```

All the objects passed exist and are logged when explicitly shown in the console.

Here are the model and the function userd :

```
@Getter
@Setter
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
@Entity
public class EventUser {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private Long id;
    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    @MapsId("eventId")
    private Event event;
    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    @MapsId("userId")
    private User user;
    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    @MapsId("userFunctionId")
    private UserFunction userFunction;
    @NotNull
    private Timestamp createdAt;
    @NotNull
    private Long createdBy;
    @NotNull
    private Timestamp modifiedAt;
    @NotNull
    private Long modifiedBy;
}
```

Function :

```
@Override
    public EventUser addEventUser(EventUser eventUser) {
        Timestamp currentTimestamp = new Timestamp(System.currentTimeMillis());

        // Check that the event, user, and userFunction properties are set
        if (eventUser.getEvent() == null || eventUser.getUser() == null || eventUser.getUserFunction() == null) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("Event, User, or UserFunction is not set in EventUser.");
        }

        eventUser.setCreatedAt(currentTimestamp);
        eventUser.setModifiedAt(currentTimestamp);

        try {
            return eventUserRepository.save(eventUser);
        } catch (DataIntegrityViolationException e) {
            logger.error("[api.events.service.impl.EventUserService] addEventUser: Data integrity violation while adding event user", e);
            throw new RuntimeException("[api.events.service.impl.EventUserService] addEventUser: Error adding event user: Data integrity violation", e);
        } catch (JpaSystemException e) {
            logger.error("JPA system exception while adding event", e);
            throw new RuntimeException("[api.events.service.impl.EventUserService] addEventUser: Error adding event user: Database error", e);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            logger.error("[api.events.service.impl.EventUserService] addEventUser: An error occurred while adding event user", e);
            throw new RuntimeException("Error adding event user", e);
        }
    }
```

Thank you for your help !